# Paul J Nahin. Story of minus one, I'm stumped on page 5.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

every time I try to read this book and follow the logic I fail on just page 5 where it states near the bottom

> $${1 \over x } + 14 x + \sqrt{{1\over x^2} + 196 x^2 } = 12,$$ 
> which is easily put into the form given above,
> $$ 172 x = 336 x^2 +24.$$

(From  [An Imaginary Tale, The Story of $\sqrt{-1}$](http://www.pucrs.br/ciencias/viali/tic_literatura/livros/Paul%20J.%20Nahin%20-%20An%20Imaginary%20Tale%20The%20Story%20of%20i%20the%20Square%20Root%20of%20Minus%20One.pdf) )

But try as I may I cannot manipulate the square root equation into the quadratic stated, easy indeed!
A lifetime working an an electrical engineer using j notation has been of no help to me.
Please put me right if you are able.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please include the actual equation in the book and the form you are trying to put it into? Otherwise it's impossible for anyone who doesn't also own the book to be able to help you.

Comment: When you [edit] the question to type in the equation and some of the context, please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Note:  $(\frac1x+14x)^2=\frac1{x^2}+196x^2+28$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $x$, then square both sides, and finally divide through by $x$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to isolate the square root on one side and then squaring both sides to get rid of it, yielding:

$$\frac{1}{x^2}+196x^2=\left(12-14x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2$$

You can then expand the RHS and simplify to get the required form.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\frac{1}{x}+14x=y$ then we can rewrite the equation as $y+\sqrt{y^2-28}=12 \rightarrow \sqrt{y^2-28}=12-y$

Squaring both parts we get: $y^2-28=144-24y+y^2$ or $24y=172$ or $$24(\frac{1}{x}+14x)=172$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you Paula and Vasya. All clear now. Each time I attempted the expansion, I now see from my notes, I repeatedly made the same trivial mistake while collecting terms even though the attempts were years apart. I also see where the expression "you can't teach old dogs new tricks come from" Thank you again for taking the time to set me straight